# Передача строковых констант в библиотеку Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, dll, библиотеки

Раньше, когда у меня была *Delphi 7*, на ней была написана dll и к ней приложение на ней же – все было нормально. В dll передавалась строковая константа.
Сейчас Delphi 10.2, пришлось dll под него заточить.
Пришлось изменить вызов dll в приложении, на

```
function TRANSMIT_DATAS_DLL(F_Name_current_application: WideString): Integer; stdcall; far; external 'setting.dll';
```

т.е. с `String` на `WideString`.

Все хорошо передается, если `F_Name_current_application` – это **var**.
Но у меня этот параметр *const* (н-р:

> const F_Name_current_application = ‘Project.exe’

), если я передаю его в таком виде, то ошибка:

> …raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at
>   0x0419a232: write of address 0x004ed6a0'.

**Вопрос**:
Можно ли как-то передать константу, или всетаки без переменных не обойтись?

P.S.
Ну такой же эффект в принципе при явной передачи строки ('TRANSMIT_DATAS_DLL('Project.exe');')

Comment: Если в Delphi 7 это был `string`, то в 10.2 это должен стать `AnsiString`, а не `WideString` если я ничего не путаю. Потому что `WideString` и в 7 и в 10.2 версиях одинаковый. Если же вы и библиотеку и приложение компилируете в 10.2, то почему бы просто не оставить String?

Comment: - Приложение продолжаю компилировать в Delphi 7  **-** C *AnsiString* я тоже сначало думал, но при этом вместо нормального шрифта **передаются иероглифы**. А с "WideString" - все нормально

Comment: Причем, да, если приложение компилировать под Delphi 10.2, то ничего менять не нужно, даже константы работают

Comment: `const F_Name_current_application = ‘Project.exe’` - это ведь UnicodeString, если установки не поменяны.

Comment: и всеравно при таком раскладе в дебагере, в конце значения строки выпадает иероглифы например **'BasePath'#0'몭몭몭'#$ABAB#$ABAB**. А если это значение показать при помощи *showmessage* - иероглифов не видно

Comment: http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2011/12/delphi.html#n5 правило №6. Это я к "если компилировать под 10.2 то ничего менять не нужно". Ну и - в exe прототип изменен. А в dll случайно не "дельфовый" string остался? Там же тоже нужно менять на WideString

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего делать это через указатели. Объявляете в dll такую функцию:

```
function MyFunc(const AStr: PAnsiChar): Integer;
```

Вызов функции:

```
var
  VMyStr: string;
begin
  MyFunc(PAnsiChar(VMyStr));
  ...
```

Получение строки внутри dll:

```
function MyFunc(const AStr: PAnsiChar): Integer;
var
  VStr: string;
begin
  VStr := string(AStr);
  ...
end;
```

Вместо PAnsiChar можно использовать PWideChar. Главное условие - использовать один и тот же тип и в dll и в приложении. Тогда всё будет работать вне зависимости от версии компилятора dll и приложения.